Getting "unauthorised" error when trying to create connection from Grafana to InfluxDB
I'm trying to setup Grafana to use InfluxDB as a data source. When I try to configure the connection I get an Unauthorised error in Grafana. The grafana log shows
err="InfluxDB returned error: Unauthorized"

It's trying to get this URL
url="http://localhost:8086/query?db=network_data&epoch=ms&q=SHOW+measurements"

If I try manually with curl I get the same.
I'm really new to both pieces. Not understanding how you configure this. I can login fine to the InfluxDB dashboard and see all my data.

Please try to follow this guide as it explains step by step, seems like you are missing a few things: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/tools/grafana/
